# How to addClass to a photo/caption array for portrait images?

Tags: javascript, arrays, gallery, addclass

I have the gallery working except i can't specify the class for each image so that I can change the proportions of vertical images. this is what I have so far.

the code :

```
    var photos = new Array(), captions = new Array(); classes = new Array(); 
    var zero=0

    photos[0]="img/bg_array/img1.jpg";
    photos[1]="img/bg_array/img2.jpg";
    photos[2]="img/bg_array/img3.jpg";
    photos[3]="img/bg_array/img4.jpg";
    photos[4]="img/bg_array/img5.jpg";

    captions[0] = "one";
    captions[1] = "two";
    captions[2] = "three";
    captions[3] = "four";
    captions[4] = "five";

    classes[0] = "hor";
    classes[1] = "ver";
    classes[2] = "hor";
    classes[3] = "hor";
    classes[4] = "hor";

    function backward(){
        if (zero>0){
            window.status=''
            zero--
            document.images.photoarray.src=photos[zero]
            document.images.photoarray.addClass=classes[zero]
            document.descform.desc.innerHTML=captions[zero];
        }
        else { 
        window.status='Gallery Start'
        }
    }


    function forward(){
        if (zero<photos.length-1){
            zero++
            document.images.photoarray.src=photos[zero]
            document.images.photoarray.addClass=classes[zero]
            document.descform.desc.innerHTML=captions[zero];
        }
        else {
            window.status='Gallery End'
            document.descform.desc.innerHTML=captions[zero] + ' (End of Series)';
        }
    }


</script>
```

the html :

```
<span>
    <img src="img/bg_array/img1.jpg" name="photoarray" oncontextmenu="return false;" class="hor">
    <form name="descform">
        <textarea name="desc" onFocus="this.blur()">one</textarea>
    </form>
    <div>
        <p id="back" onClick="backward()"></p>
        <p id="next" onClick="forward()"></p>
    </div>
</span>
```

any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: classes is undefined, change ; to , at variable declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.images doesn't provide the method addClass.

You can try this:

```
document.getElementsByName("photoarray")[0].setAttribute("class", classes[zero]);
```

or give the img tag an id to get access with

```
document.getElementById("xyz").setAttribute("class", classes[zero]);
```

Comment: That first option is exactly what i was looking for, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This may help.

```
this.setAttribute("class", classes[zero]);
```